# Powershell Script wont add $PSDefaultParameterValues to $profile

Tags: powershell, profile, string-literals, string-interpolation, default-parameters

I'm writing a quick Powershell script to import modules and update some default parameters on various machines.  I'm running into an issue where in my script when I add `$PSDefaultParameterValues` to the $profile it changes to `System.Management.Automation.DefaultParameterDictionary` which then throws an error of not being recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

Here is the code in my ps1 script

`Add-Content -Path $PROFILE -Value "$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{}"`

Here is what gets added to the profile

`System.Management.Automation.DefaultParameterDictionary = @{}`

I've tried everything from using Set-Content to using variables to avoid quotation confusion.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to [tonypags' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72807515/45375):

- *Double*-quoted PowerShell strings (`"..."`) are [*expandable* strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), i.e they perform *string interpolation* of embedded variable references (e.g. `$PSDefaultParameterValues`) and subexpressions (e.g. `$(1 + 2)`)
- *Single*-quoted strings (`'...'`) are [*verbatim* strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), i.e. their content is used as-is (verbatim, literally).

---

Thus, the automatic `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable was *expanded* in your `"..."` string, which in essence means it was replaced with its `.ToString()` representation - which in this case is simply the *type name* of the variable's value.

- If your *entire* string is meant to be used *verbatim*, use `'...'` quoting, as shown in tonypags' answer.
- If you do need expansions (string interpolation), but need to *selectively suppress* them, *escape* `$` characters as `` `$ ``, using `` ` `` (a backtick), PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters), as shown in the following example:

  ```bash
   $enc = 'utf8'
   # Note the backtick (`) before $PSDefaultParameterValues.
   # NOTE: It is only the *outer* quoting that determines 
   #       whether expansion is performed.
   Add-Content -Path $PROFILE `
               -Value "`$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ '*:Encoding' = '$enc' }"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes

```
Add-Content -Path $PROFILE -Value '$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{}'
```

These are literal strings so any variables will not expand.